# The current path, home/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, path, web-frameworks, django-2.2

I have two apps on my project- one is accounts and home
home app url - http://localhost:8000/home/ is rising an error that the 
 current path, home/, didn't match any of these.

I'm using django version 2.2.4
and i'm using regular expression on my home url pattern

**My home app url**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
]
```

**My home view**

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('It worked !..')
```

**Main url**

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),  # automatically takes to login page
    path(r'^account/', include(('accounts.urls','accounts'), namespace='accounts')),
    path(r'^home/', include(('home.urls','home'), namespace='home')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

]
```

i'm expecting simple message on the browser that is 'It worked!..'

Comment: it is urls.py of the home app and project URL means the main urls.py which handles all apps URLs

Comment: Remove `^` in `r'^$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using django 2.2.4 then, there is no need for using regular expression in URL pattern. change

```
path(r'^home/', include(('home.urls','home'), namespace='home'))
```

to

```
path('home/', include('home.urls'))
```

Similarly, change

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
```

to

```
path('', views.home,  name = 'home')
```

For further info on URL dispatcher check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score -2):

Simply change this to

```py
path('', views.home)
```

It will work.

Comment: Please make your answer clearer, why does your code work? Simply stating that 'it will work' isn't good enough

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? Also: Please refrain from saying "simply" - that doesn't help others who don't find something to be simple.